# Why does rock image does not move alongside the mouse when in motion although I called the node and got its position-Godot Game Engine

Tags: position, godot, gdscript

I am trying to get my rock.png to move to the side(+x axis) when my mouse is moving. You can see that _target is the position of the event and the event is the mouse moving.

I then got the node image and set it to a variable.
In the else statement I made the rock.position the position of the _target and gave it somee space away from the _target

I want this to move because my camera moves and I want it to move with the flow of the camera

``

```
extends Camera2D

const zone = 10
onready var rock = get_node("rocks_png_1")

func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        var _target = event.position 
        if _target.length() < zone:
            self.position = Vector2(640,350)
        else:
            self.position = _target.normalized() * (_target.length() - zone) * 0.5
            rock.position = Vector2(int(_target)+40, int(_target)+20)
```

``

From the code I used above I get this error

```
Invalid get Index 'position' (on base: 'TextureRact')
```

I tried just using the same code as I used in my self.position for the camera that made it move, but when I try it for the rock.position it gives me an error that tells me I need a Vector?

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid get Index 'position' (on base: 'TextureRact')

The error is telling you that `TextureRect` does not have a `position` property.

What happens is that a `TextureRect` is a `Control` which are positioned differently from `Node2D` (`Camera2D` is a `Node2D`). You can try using `rect_position` with it. Although I think you would be better off using a `Sprite` instead of a `TextureRect` (`Sprite` is a `Node2D`).

Notice that your `TextureRect` is a child of the `Camera2D` in the scene tree. Well, a `Node2D` would move with its parent automatically. So changing it to `Sprite` would negate the need of the line of code you are using to move it.

… Actually, due to the way `Camera2D` works (it has drag and limits) you might still want do something (depending what your goal is). So, know that the `get_camera_screen_center` method will give you the actual visual center of the screen (which is not the target of the `Camera2D`, again due to drag and limits).

Comment: Oh ok, I see. I will change to a sprite and see if it functions, but can you explain what you mean by "a Node2D would move with its parent automatically." Do you mean the position of the node will always assume what its parents position is?

Comment: @Temmy The position of the child will be relative to the parent (you can think it as being an offset from the parent, but know the same rule also applies to rotation and scaling). So when the parent moves the child moves accordingly. For example, a common setup for `KinematicBody2D` or `RigidBody2D` is to add a child `Sprite`, so the physics body moves according to physics (with collisions and so on), and the `Sprite` follows automatically.